# wget recursively with -np option still ascends to parent directory

Tags: ubuntu, download, wget, recursive, mirroring

tl;dr: will `wget --no-parrent -r ' download from a directory above the given url's directory?

when using wget to download, say images, recursively from example.com/a/b with the -r and -np options, will a picture that is under example.com/a/c/ be downloaded when example.com/a/b/ delivers a html-file containing a link to the picture? if so, how do i get all pictures, that are in a folder and it's subfolders and only those? 
the description of the option --no-parent says "Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively". anyway directory browsing delivers a link to the parent directory, which wget will follow, despite mentioned option. now what did i miss?

edit: using GNU Wget 1.12

Answer (score 6):

I just ran some tests with **WGET 1.10.2 for Windows** and it worked as expected.

Make sure to add a trailing slash to the directory to indicate for example, that *b* is a sub-directory of *a* and not a file in it:

```
> wget … hxxp://example.com/a/b/
```

If that still doesn’t work, try specifying some of recursion exclusion options:

- `--reject=htm,html`
- `--ignore-tags=a`
- `--exclude-directories=http://example.com/a/c/`

Comment: Adding add a trailing slash didnt do, --reject=htm,html neither and there are too many subdirs to exclude manually. anyway im not looking for a work around, i wonder what -np is good for or if its broken.

Comment: But it’s not, I tried it and it worked. Perhaps it’s your copy; where is it from? Linux? A Windows port? What version is it?…

Comment: it is GNU Wget 1.12 on ubuntu

Comment: i tried it on another site, too, and it worked, curiously enough.

Comment: Then it’s probably something about that one site or its contents. When I did the test, I specifically created a directory structure matching what you described, put some image files in them, set Indexes on, and put an HTML file in one of the directories (`a/b`) containing a hyperlink to an image in the other (`a/c/img.png`). It worked fine: `a/b/*` got downloaded, but `a/c/` was not even created.

Comment: I was just having this problem (ascending to parent even with `-np`). I did a quick search, landed here, saw my old answer, added the trailing slash, and bam! it worked. ☺